# Why are the files in my .qrc resource file showing up empty?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to load in SSL cert files from a .qrc resource file. It shows the entry when I query the directory for an entry list with: `QStringList apples = QDir (":/").entryList();`

The output of which is:

> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "items"
>
> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "particleresources"
>
> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "particles"
>
> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "plugins"
>
> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "qml"
>
> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "qt-project.org"
>
> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "qtmultimediaquicktools"
>
> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "QtQuick"
>
> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "scenegraph"
>
> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "shaders"
>
> D TAPMobile: (null):0 ((null)): "SSLcomDVCA_2.crt"

I set the path of the cert using `certPath = ":/SSLcomDVCA_2.crt"; // Dev Cert`

I also load the resource file with `RESOURCES += resources.qrc certs.qrc # uncomment for publishing` in the .pro file.

When going through debugging looking at the cert path and the cert file I get the following: http://bit.ly/1MngyId

I also explicitly init the resource file with: `Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resources);`

This is the last remaining hurdle before deployment to the app store, so any help would be fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is a follow up with an explanation I posted elsewhere but the answer is relevant. It was empty because I wasn't actually hitting the proper path where the file was. Below is the fix and my explanation of what it was happening.*

I've found the "issue" and the answer to my problem. Although I think the problem would be a QT bug or my understanding of string definition is wrong. I set the resource file called `certs.qrc` when I put the two certificates for dev and prod. I created the file definition and used the path I got by right clicking on the resource file and copying it's path. See below for the full definition of the SSL, hopefully this will serve as an example for QT SSL as well because I could barely find any of those either.

Here is my certs file without the 'RCC' header because it seems to break block quotes:

> ```
> <qresource prefix="/certs">
>     <file>GandiStandardSSLCA2.crt</file>
>     <file>SSLcomDVCA_2.crt</file>
> </qresource>
> ```

Below is the definition for that certificate file:

> ```
> // SSL socket set up
> QFile certFile(":/certs/GandiStandardSSLCA2.crt");
> if(certFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
> {
>     qDebug() << "File opened";
> }
> else {
>     qDebug() << "Boooo";
> }
> QSslCertificate cert(&certFile, QSsl::Pem);
> forgotPwSocket = new QSslSocket(this);
> forgotPwSocket->addCaCertificate(cert);
> ```

All this is currently functional. make sure you run qmake in order to get the resource files compiled.

So now, my explanation as to why I was having a problem. I was using a different deploy method before for the certs where I was deploying the entire assets folder. That works for Android by not iOS so I decided to go with qrc instead. While I was trying to implement the `/assets` folder deployment I was using an **ifdef to define the string of the path depending on if it was iOS or Android.** I removed the ifdef, and all my problems went away, it was now able to find the files at the path. The string is a member of my network object and I would define it at run time using the ifdef. During all my debugging, it was the correct path as shown in the inspector. Realizing that using the .qrc resource eliminated the need to define the path based on Android/iOS I hardcoded the path value as stated above. Once I did that, it started working. The path name is the same as it was in the debugger with the ifdef in place so I'm not sure why/where this was breaking. If anyone has any further insight it would be fantastic to hear. Hopefully this will help anyone having a similar issue or getting SSL working in QT in general!